# function to get label value based on dropdownlist item value using c#

Tags: c#, html-select

I have a dropdownlist bound to a database, and I have a label.

I need to set the label text equal to a dropdownlist item text, based on its item value (which is equal to a session variable value in this example).

I don't know how to get the value from every item and return the text.

This is my try, but it's not working.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CargarDDLCentroC();
    lbcentro.Text = Centrocosto(Convert.ToInt32(Session["numero"].ToString()));
}


private string Centrocosto(int m)
{
    string res = "";

    for (var i = 1; i <= 20; i++)
    {
        if (i == m)
        {
            res = DDLCentroC.Items[i].Text;
            break;
        }
    }

    return res;
}
```

I get the following error: "Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection"

Comment: Where do you store "numero" in the session?

Comment: so can't you just get the `DDLCentroC.SelectedItem.Text`??

Comment: I don't need a selected item for the label text, but just the item text based on its value

Comment: the session variable is just for this example, but it can be any number and it should match an item value in the dropdownlist

Comment: why not  res = DDLCentroC.Items[m].Text; and forget the whole loop...

Comment: @Sam actually that's a better solution, but I need to change DDLCentroC.Items[m].Text; for a function that works with the value instead of the index